# Obtaining Radial Distribution Functions using MDAnalysis

Tags: python, physics, chemistry, mdanalysis

I am running a simple benzene simulation in GROMOS54a7.
I want to calculate the RDF of the center of masses of each benzene molecule, using MDAnalysis 1.0.0.

Is this possible? I have create the rdf for the C molecules g_cc(r) using the following code in a Jupyter Notebook:

```
import MDAnalysis
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline
import MDAnalysis.analysis.rdf as mda
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

u = MDAnalysis.Universe("739-c6h6-MolDynamics.tpr","739-c6h6-MolDynamics_good-pbc.xtc")
s1 = u.select_atoms("resid 0 and type CAro")
s2 = u.select_atoms("not (resid 0) and type CAro")
rdf = mda.InterRDF(s1, s2)
rdf.run()
```

I want to take each benzene molecule (each benzene molecule is a residue in my simulation), calculate its COM and run a script like the one above on it. Is it possible to do something like that?

A general question about RDFs: does the method I have used above construct an RDF using every frame of my trajectory? I don't know if this was made clear in the documentation, so I apologize if this is an obvious question.

Thank you for any advice you have!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be useful to make it possible to use CG groups as native atoms in order to reuse the analysis tools in MDAnalysis.

Here is a quick fix that mimics the MDAnalysis group and presents a new `positions` property. The new `positions` provides the centre of geometry instead of the actual positions. I also overwrite the **len** to convey that only one bead is being used for the CG element.

```
import MDAnalysis as mda
import numpy as np
import MDAnalysis.analysis.rdf
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

u = mda.Universe('sys_solv.pdb','prod.dcd')

class CG:
    def __init__(self, ag):
        self.ag = ag
        self.universe = self.ag.universe
        self.trajectory = self.ag.universe.trajectory

    @property
    def positions(self):
        return np.array([self.ag.center_of_geometry()])

    def __len__(self):
        return 1

cg_selection = u.select_atoms('resid 1')
cg_atom = CG(cg_selection.atoms)
waters = u.select_atoms('name O')

rdf = MDAnalysis.analysis.rdf.InterRDF(cg_atom, waters)
rdf.run() 
plt.plot(rdf.bins, rdf.rdf)
```

Verification: I selected a single atom for the CG bead and it reproduces the original RDF.

MDAnalysis uses the entire trajectory. You might in the documentation the start/stop/step parameters for the .run() function which allows you to narrow down which frames to use specifically.